# Android 11 file not delete from download folder after uninstall an install again

Tags: android, android-11, android-storage

In android 11 I saved photos in Download dir `/storage/emulated/0/Download/SavedImages/` when I delete file using `File.delete()` it's working perfectly.

But issue is when I saved files to Download dir `/storage/emulated/0/Download/SavedImages/` after that I uninstall my App and re-install and I try to delete file using `File.delete()` the file not delete why?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have read/write/delete access to files in `Download/`, except for those that your app *installation* put there. Any files downloaded by your app there are usable by that app installation, but if the user uninstalls/reinstalls the app, then those files are inaccessible, just as are files put there by anything else.

Comment: ok! whats solution or any  way around  of this problem

Comment: @code4rox: Your app should not put files in `Download/` that your app needs again after uninstall/reinstall. Use the Storage Access Framework and let the user decide where documents come from and go to.